# Linux configuration automated integrity checking and versionning

Tags: linux, configuration-management

I'm looking for a tool like tripwire on Linux.
Tripwire allow to designate folder you want to monitor and the program alert you when a change is made to a file.
What I want is to identify which file has been altered and also what was the modifcation, and what was the original file.
It could be considered as a Tripwire with a versionning when someone modify a file.

Comment: For monitoring, there's `inotify` on Linux, see [How to execute a command whenever a file changes?](http://superuser.com/q/181517/143340) on our sister-site (and also see [this article](http://stefan.buettcher.org/cs/fschange/)) – but that covers only part of your request. For the remaining part, take a look e.g. at [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/mikesmullin/6401258) to be used as a wrapper, you could specify your own actions this way (e.g. copy the changed file, or use Git/SVN to trigger a "checkin" for versioning).